# IMU noise cancelation in DRCsim 2.5

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I looked at the noise added to the IMU of Atlas and I saw that the acceleration has a bias of +-0.1 m/s/s in all direction, and the noise distribution in Gauusian.
However, the orientation received from the IMU is filtered, with no bias and hardly any noise.

Is there a filter implemented in the calculation of the orientation?

Thanks,
Oded

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2701/imu-noise-cancelation-in-drcsim-2.5/) by [odedy86](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/297/odedy86/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As noted in [pull request #421](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/421/added-noise-to-rates-and-accels-with-test), noise is added to acceleration and velocity data, but not to orientation data.  The provided orientation is extracted directly from the underlying physics engine.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0